# displaying  json data in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a var and passed JSON data(comma seperated values) to it, but when I want to display json data - it only returns null. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data1 = [
    {order:"145",country:"Dubai",employee:"permanent",customer:"self"}
];  

document.write(data1);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question, and what does the title have to do with the content of your post?

Comment: @Eimantas I think you took too many liberties in that edit; it certainly was not clear that the poster meant what you wrote.

Comment: @lanzz Probably. I derived the question from the piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do it like this:

```
var data1 = [{order:"145",country:"Dubai",employee:"permanent",customer:"self"} ];  

data1.forEach(function(data){
    document.write(data.order);
    document.write(data.country);
    document.write(data.employee);
    document.write(data.customer);
});
```

or you can do it like this

```
var data1 = [
    {order:"145",country:"Dubai",employee:"permanent",customer:"self"}
];  

$.each(data1[0], function(key, value){
    document.write(key + " " + value); 
});
```

Either way, storing just one object in the list makes this answer a bit redundant unless I show you how to loop over multiple objects.

```
var data1 = [
    {order:"145",country:"Dubai",employee:"permanent",customer:"self"},
    {order:"212",country:"Abu-Dhabi",employee:"permanent",customer:"Tom"}
];  

data1.forEach(function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        document.write(key+" "+value);
    });
});
```

I'm using a mix of jQuery here aswell, which might not be optimal but atleast it serves to show that there are multiple ways to accomplishing what you need.

Also, the forEach() method on arrays is a MDN developed method so it might not be crossbrowser compliant, just a heads up!

If you want pure JS this is one of the ways to go

```
var data1 = [
    {order:"145",country:"Dubai",employee:"permanent",customer:"self"},
    {order:"212",country:"Abu-Dhabi",employee:"permanent",customer:"Tom"}
];  

for(json in data1){
    for(objs in data1[json]){
        document.write(objs + " : " + data1[json][objs]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple and quick printing of JSON, one can do something like below and pretty much same goes for objects as well;

```
 var json = {
        "title" : "something",
        "status" : true,
        "socialMedia": [{
            "facebook": 'http://facebook.com/something'
        }, {
            "twitter": 'http://twitter.com/something'
        }, {
            "flickr": 'http://flickr.com/something'
        }, {
            "youtube": 'http://youtube.com/something'
        }]
    };
```

and now to print on screen, a simple for in loop is enough, but please not e, it won't print array instead will print [object Object]. for simplicity of answer, i won't go in deep to print arrays key and value in screen.

Hope that this will be usefull for someone. Cheers!

```
for(var i in json) {
    document.writeln('<strong>' + i + '</strong>' +json[i] + '<br>');
    console.log(i +  ' ' + json[i])
}
```